# Limit comparison test for checking the convergence of an infinite series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, intuition

Here's the limit comparison test from an online source:
$$\lim_\limits{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n}}{b_{n}}=c$$
Where $a_{n}$ and $b_{n}$ are the general terms of two different infinite series.
If $c$ is finite and **positive**, both infinite series will converge or both will diverge.

Here's how I try to understand the limit comparison test:
A series will converge/diverge based on its behaviour as $n$ approaches $\infty$. If the a series divided by another series results in a positive constant, they will have the same "convergence behaviour" (don't know how to put this into words) and will both converge or both diverge.

Intuitively, why does $c$ have to be positive?
Even if $c$ is negative, it shouldn't affect the limit comparison test. I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The essence of my answer is the following example (please read below for a proper attribution, and a verification).

Example. Let $a_n=\frac{(−1)^{n-1}}n$ and $b^n=\frac{(−1)^n}n+\frac1{n\ln n}$.
In this case $\sum a_n$ converges and $\sum b_n$ diverges while $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n}=-1$.

Intuitively, allowing $c<0$ would only make sense if you allow the $a_n$ (and $b_n$) to take negative as well as positive values. Then we must deal with conditionally convergent series. These are "less stable under tweaks" (than series with all positive terms), and it turns out that we could tweak the alternating harmonic series (which as is known is convergent) into an alternating series which is divergent, yet the ratio of the common terms of the two series is a finite nonzero number (whether negative or positive is not that important). Here are more details.

The way I understand or interpret the question is the following.

We *do not* require that $a_n$ and $b_n$ are only non-negative terms. 
We assume that $\lim_\limits{n\to \infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n}=c<0$, that is $-\infty<c<0$.
Could we conclude that either:
(i) $\sum a_n$ and $\sum b_n$ are both convergent,
or
(ii) $\sum a_n$ and $\sum b_n$ are both divergent?

The answer is *NO*, as explained below.

First, the essential modification of the usual limit comparison test is that we allow the $a_n$ and $b_n$ to take both positive and negative values. It is not really important that we allow $c<0$. Indeed, if $c<0$ we may replace $a_n$ with $-a_n$ and use that (obviously) the series 
$\sum a_n$ and the series $\sum-a_n=-\sum a_n$ are either both convergent or both divergent. 
(This procedure would of course replace $c$ with $-c$ .)

In one of the comments to her/his answer @user provided a
[link to the following paper (preprint?)](https://www.disei.unifi.it/upload/sub/pubblicazioni/repec/flo/workingpapers/storicodimad/2003/dimadwp2003-01.pdf)
*The comparison test - Not just for nonnegative series*
Michele Longo, Vincenzo Valori, October 2003.

It seems to me that @user's interpretation of the OP question was different than mine, and she/he seems to have not indicated the relevance (to my interpretation, at least ) of Example 7 in the paper referenced above.

**Example 7**. Let $a_n=\frac{(−1)^n}n$ and $b^n=\frac{(−1)^n}n+\frac1{n\ln n}$.
In this case $\sum a_n$ converges and $\sum b_n$ diverges while $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n}=1$.

The authors did not provide a proof, but I assume only 
because the verification is easy.
(E.g. $\sum\frac1{n\ln n}$ is divergent by the integral test, since the improper integral $\int_3^\infty\frac{1\ dx}{x\ln x}$ is easily seen to be divergent, after making a substitution $u=\ln x$, a standard example in most calculus books.
Also, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{b_n}{a_n}=$ $1+\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{(−1)^n}{\ln n}=1$ . So $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n}=\frac11=1$ .)

(Also, of course, just to note it one more time, if we let $a_n=-\frac{(−1)^n}n=\frac{(−1)^{n-1}}n$ then we would have that
$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n}=-1$, while 
$\sum a_n$ converges and $\sum b_n$ diverges).

Edit (addressing a comment by @helpme).
Intuitively that is correct, alternating series are to blame. More precisely, series that are not absolutely convergent (that is, series that are only conditionally convergent), by definition this means $\sum_na_n$ is convergent but $\sum_n|a_n|=\infty$ is not convergent. In such a series there will be infinitely many positive and infinitely many negative terms, but the signs may not necessarily alternate according to a $(-1)^n$ rule. Something like $1-\frac12-\frac13+\frac14-\frac15-\frac16...$.
But if one of the series is absolutely convergent (e.g. if $\sum_n|a_n|$ is convergent) and if $\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n}=c\in(-\infty,0)$
 then we would necessarily have $\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}\frac{|a_n|}{|b_n|}=|c|\in(0,\infty)$ so $\sum_n|b_n|$ is convergent, which in turn implies that $\sum_nb_n$ is also convergent.

Comment: What I've explained is that if the general terms have eventually constant sign then we can always apply LCT and it works fine for $c$ positive or negative. I'll revise that to make it more clear and add the observations made by comments.

Comment: There was indeed also some typo. Now It should be clear.

Comment: Thank you for the example. So the reason why we cannot use series with some terms negative in general is due to alternating series (in the third paragraph)?

Comment: @helpme Yes, alternating series are to blame, and more generally conditionally (but not absolutely) convergent series. I made an edit with some details at the end of my answer. Thank you, you are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

The comparison test is for series of positive numbers. Therefore, you cannot possibly have $c<0$. And if you had $c=0$, then you could have $a_n=\frac1{n^2}$ and $b_n=\frac1n$. Then $c$ *is* $0$, the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges, and the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$ diverges.

Comment: Why must the series only have positive numbers and not negative numbers

Comment: Because this is an exercise about the comparaison test and the statement of the comparaison test contains the hypothesis that we are dealing with series of positive numbers (the statement would be false without that assumption).

Comment: Is it ok to hypothesise that the series can have both positive and negative numbers, and then as a result $c$ can be $>0$ or $<0$

Comment: No, it is not, since that is not the statement of the comparaison test.

Comment: Since the comparison test has to state that each term is positive (and therefore $c>0$), will it go wrong when the some terms are negative? Or is there some other test that will hypothesise about series that have negative terms. It feels bad to have the comparison test limited to positive terms, so I'd like to find a workaround

Comment: You cannot deduce from the hypothesis that each $a_n$ and each $b_n$ is positive that $c>0$. The only conclusion that you can get is that $c\geqslant0$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Regardell how the LCT is stated, it seems to be a legitimate question to ask: Suppose that $\lim_\limits{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n}}{b_{n}}=c\in(-\infty,0)$. Could we conclude that $\sum a_n$ and $\sum b_n$ are either both convergent or both divergent? The interesting case being when some $b_n>0$ (and $a_n<0$) but some $b_n<0$ (and $a_n>0$). (If all $a_n<0$ then we may just replace $\sum a_n$ with $-\sum a_n$.)

Comment: @helpme when you allow some of the terms to be negative, and some positive, then you could indeed get examples when $-\infty<c<0$. But, you cannot conclude that either (i) $\sum a_n$ and $\sum b_n$ are both convergent, or (ii) $\sum a_n$ and $\sum b_n$ are both divergent. Please see my answer for a specific example (that I found online, following a link provided in *user*'s answer).

Answer (score 1):

Your intuition is right, indeed what we need to apply LCT is that the general terms of the two series have eventually constant sign.

Indeed suppose that eventually $a_n\ge 0$, $b_n >0$ and $\exists c\in \mathbb R$

$$\frac{a_n}{b_n}\to c>0$$

by limit comparison test we can conclude that

- $\sum b_n<\infty \implies \sum a_n <\infty$
- $\sum b_n=\infty \implies \sum a_n =\infty$

Then let $d_n=-b_n <0$ and we obtain

$$\frac{a_n}{d_n}\to c< 0$$

therefore we can conclude again in the same way by limit comparison test also for $c$ negative.

Note also that, assuming that eventually $a_n\ge 0$, $b_n >0$, limit comparison test also works for the following extreme cases

- $\sum b_n <\infty \, \land\,\frac{a_n}{b_n}\to 0 \implies \sum a_n <\infty$
- $\sum b_n =\infty \, \land\,\frac{a_n}{b_n}\to \infty \implies \sum a_n =\infty$

Comment: Actually, I think that c=0 shouldn't work because $a_{n}$ must be (approaching) 0 and $b_{n}$ can be anything (big or small). Other than that thank you for giving a more mathematical way of describing what I was trying to write

Comment: @helpme Yes $c=0$ works, I'l give you some references. As also $c=\infty$ works for the divergent case.

Comment: @helpme Refer to [here](https://math.oregonstate.edu/home/programs/undergrad/CalculusQuestStudyGuides/SandS/SeriesTests/limit_comparison.html) and [here](https://www.disei.unifi.it/upload/sub/pubblicazioni/repec/flo/workingpapers/storicodimad/2003/dimadwp2003-01.pdf).

Comment: Oh. Series A will converge/diverge if and only if Series B converges/diverges when $c>0$, but when $c=0$ Series B diverging implies that Series A converges. (Don't know why the first webpage says that Series B converging implies that Series A converges when $c=0$)

Comment: @helpme When $\sum b_n$ converges and $a_n/b_n \to 0$ then also $\sum a_n$ converges and when $\sum b_n$ diverges and $a_n/b_n \to \infty$ then also $\sum a_n$ diverges.

Comment: @user You answer is correct, but my interpretation of the question seems different that yours (mine, allowing some $a_n>0$ and some $a_n<0$), and in particular Example 7 in one of the links that you provided seems relevant (and I posted an answer, accordingly). Thank you !

Comment: @Mirko I’ll take a look to it! Thanks

Comment: Admittedly, the question is somewhat unclear, but as I read it, the statement being considered is "If $a_n / b_n \to c > 0$, then $\sum a_n$ converges if and only if $\sum b_n$ converges (equivalently, $\sum a_n$ diverges if and only if $\sum b_n$ diverges)."  This statement is no longer true when $c = 0$, as the conclusion will no longer be biconditional.  As such, I think that your first sentence is *extremely* misleading.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Please read carefully. As I’ve noticed at first I’m considering the “convergent case only” that is $\sum b_n$ convergent. In this case also for $c=0$ we can conclude that $\sum a_n$ converges. The same clear explanation was given in my previous comment here where also the extended divergent case is covered. Thanks

Comment: @user I had no issues understanding what you meant, on first reading (as indicated in my first comment yesterday). I suspect, I unwittingly brought the wrath of a moderator upon your answer when I made noise yesterday on meta and a chat room about that other answer. I read your answer again, I saw "the convergence case" on top of your answer (after I saw your answer went down a vote and read the critical comment, and before your reply to said comment), I guess that was missed by the commentator. I may have overlooked a typo, don't know, but I know what you were describing and it was correct.